# What is a driver stack in the Windows OS?

Tags: windows, drivers

What is a driver stack in the Windows OS?

I was reading material in [NDIS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_Driver_Interface_Specification) and wan't know what is it.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! The more effort you put into your questions, the better both the quality and quantity of the answers you'll get. Recommend clarifying and expanding your question. Are you asking what a network stack is, what a driver interface is, what NDIS is, ...? What resources have you already looked at but not been satisfied by?

Comment: @TJ Very good welcoming! On the question: *"The NDIS is a library of functions often referred to as a **"wrapper" that hides the underlying complexity of the NIC hardware** and serves as a standard interface for level 3 network protocol drivers and the hardware level MAC drivers."* http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_Driver_Interface_Specification

Answer (score 5):

The [Windows Driver Model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Driver_Model) (WDM) uses a layered approach in which a given device is served by at least two drivers: a **bus** driver and a
**function** driver. A device might also have filter drivers that add value or modify the behavior of the device. The chain of drivers that serve a device is called a **driver stack**.

[image: Layered driver architecture in Windows]

(From: http://www.microsoft.com/whdc/archive/wdmoverview.mspx)

Also see: [Device Driver Introduction](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Windows_Programming/Device_Driver_Introduction), specifically [section 5](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Windows_Programming/Device_Driver_Introduction#Device_Driver_Stack) on the "Device Driver Stack."

Answer (score 1):

One good metaphor if you are familiar with design patterns is the Decorator. As an example I'd take BufferedReader and any other types of reader. So you have your basic (and possibly not very efficient reader) and you want on-the-fly without caring how to make it buffered and speed up performance so you create a BufferedReader that wraps the underlying Reader object.

The concept with driver stacks is similar - you might have your lower level driver which would write characters to device BUT you can attach on top of it another driver which would jumble every character it gets and essentially you have a whole crypto stack. That way the underlying driver doesn't know anything about whole this "magic" that is happening, it is doing exactly what it was made for - writing characters to a block device.