# Windows bluetooth driver used in every Bluetooth communication?

Tags: windows, bluetooth, driver, wdm

I'm trying to develop a filter driver for Bluetooth in Windows Vista and above, and I'm wodnering if EVERY bluetooth related action have to pass through the Windows Bluetooth driver stack or if it's just confined to Microsoft Bluetooth stack.

For instance, I have a USB bluetooth transceiver from IVT and it uses the BlueSoleil. Can BlueSoleil stack perform some bluetooth standard operations without passing through the Bluetooth driver stack?

Answer (score 1):

Every driver in stack is replaceable. As long as the replacement complies with the OS definitions (registers correctly, providing the required callbacks), it's ok as far as the OS is concerned. Each component is responsible for another part of the functionality so replacing it will replace the corresponding functionality of the driver stack. See more here: [What is a driver stack in the Windows OS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4254060/what-is-a-driver-stack-in-the-windows-os)